# Add value to Powershell output

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I've got a script which does a permission report on all mailboxes from csv file but need to add source mailbox identity string to the report.

```
import-csv "\\networkshare\import.csv" | foreach {Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $_.user | Select Identity,User,AccessRights} | Export-csv \\output.csv
```

The problem is that report is useless unless I get information about to whom other users have access. So I'm wondering how can I add something like:

```
 Select Identity,User,AccessRight,$_.user
```

But in this way it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Store `$_.User` in a variable and use calculated propeties to add it later. Ex.

```
Import-Csv "\\networkshare\import.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $u = $_.user
    Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $_.user |
    Select Identity,User,AccessRights,@{n="InputUser";e={$u}}
} | Export-csv \\output.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

You've to:

```
Select Identity,User,AccessRight,@{l="somethingAdded";e={$_.propertyToAdd}}
```

This is called a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx)

Hope that helps

Comment: You have 2 'User' properties. You may want to change the second one to 'AdditionalUsers' or something.

Comment: This answer will add the current objects `User`-property, which is already specified in the property-list. How does this help?